# How to target node app for specific platform

Tags: node.js, npm, dependencies

I have a node app that runs on a small linux device with an ARM processor. I develop in macOS and there are some platform specific dependencies in the app. Right now I just run `npm install` on the mac and copy the entire codebase, `node_modules` and all, over to the linux device. It seems to run okay but I'm not sure if it will continue to do so. Maybe it just hasn't gone down an execution path that relies on the mac specific code yet.

I suppose I could run `npm install` on the linux device but that would mean we'd have to have one available for our CI/CD pipeline to use and that's going to be a headache and probably not a realistic solution long term.

What other options are there? Is there any way to force npm to install the dependencies as if it were on the linux ARM box? I know you can do this with electron apps using [electron-packager](https://github.com/electron/electron-packager). Can this be done for non-electron node apps?

FYI, I'm using the following command to determine that there are macOS specific dependencies:

```
find node_modules -name "*.node" | xargs file
```

which returns

```
node_modules/snappy/build/Release/binding.node: Mach-O 64-bit bundle x86_64
```

Comment: If you want to create just one executable file then maybe [pkg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg) is the right thing for you

Comment: @BraveButter I saw that module but there's a disclaimer at the top that says `Disclaimer: pkg was created for use within containers and is not intended for use in serverless environments.` I'm not running this inside a container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention in the comments that [`pkg`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg) looked like a possible solution but your concerned about it being container-specific. Honestly, it's probably fine as long as you're not in a serverless environment like AWS Lambda.

Beyond that or a similar package, your obvious options are to compile on a Linux ARM device (which you've ruled out) or else get rid of the platform-specific dependencies somehow. Do you really need [`snappy`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/snappy)? Can you live with no compression or with a slower compression library? As for [`fsevents`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fsevents), I believe it is macOS only and will have no effect on other platforms. You are probably getting it as a dependency of [`chokidar`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chokidar)? It seems likely that you can ignore that one.

EDIT: Comment indicates `snappy` is installed as a dependency of `kafka-node`. `snappy` is optional in `kafka-node`. If you're not specifying snappy compression yourself, then it probably isn't being used. You can [install `kafka-node` without `snappy`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/kafka-node#what-are-these-node-gyp-and-snappy-errors) using the `--no-optional` flag: `npm install kafka-node --no-optional` Trying to use `snappy` compression then will result in a runtime error. That can potentially allow you to check locally on your macOS machine that `snappy` isn't being used.

Comment: Thanks for the info. The dependencies on `snappy` is due to a direct dependency on `kafka-node`, which must have it somewhere in its dependency tree. Turns out the dependency on `fsevents` was from `mocha` which is development only so that's fine. I'll update the question to remove that.

Comment: Would it be possible to download `kafka-node` one time on the ARM device and then store the result in the app's codebase? Kind of like a local repository just for that one package. Then I guess you'd have to reference the local file in `package.json` somehow. If we only have to download and compile the kafka dependencies one time that would be fine.

Comment: `snappy` is optional in `kafka-node`. If you're not specifying snappy compression, it probably isn't being used. You can install `kafka-node` without `snappy` using the `--no-optional` flag: `npm install kafka-node --no-optional` Trying to use `snappy` compression then will result in a runtime error. That can potentially allow you to check locally on your macOS machine that `snappy` isn't being used.

Comment: Got it. installing with `--no-optional` does remove snappy and at that point trying to use compression does result in an error like you said. I think I'll install kafka without snappy and not use compression when I send messages. Thanks for the help.